# Cannot make dictWriter to build csv

Tags: python-3.x, function, csv, dictionary, tuples

I'm new to the world of Python, so it's been quite hard to understand how dictwriter works. I'm trying to make a csv file from a dictionary in which each key has attached a tuple as value, but cannot figure out how. The code (dictionary "book" must be out of the function named "saving"):

```
book = {"000011111":("John","Doe",23,"Kendo"),"000022222":("Petra","Richards",22, "Swimming")}
import csv
def saving():
    try:
        f = open("file1.csv", "w+")
        fields = ["Card", "Name", "Surname", "Age", "Hobbie"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows({"Card": book.keys(), "Name": book[0], "Surname": book[1], "Age": book[2], "Hobbie": book[3]})
        print("Data saved to csv")
        return True
    except IOError:
        print("I/O ERROR")
        return False
saving()
```

gives me:

> KeyError: 0

Comment: Thanks ggorlen, i've  edited that (copy/paste instead of typing) and now it seems legit. Also added the last line which was missing.

Comment: python3 dictionary doesn't support indexing. book[0] or so will result in a key error, you need t lookup on the key book["000011111"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`book` is a dict. It cannot be indexed by position (e.g. `book[0]`), it has keys and values. You probably want to loop through all the key/value pairs in `book`, as in:

```
book = {"000011111":("John","Doe",23,"Kendo"),"000022222":("Petra","Richards",22, "Swimming")}
def saving():
    try:
        for codekey, first_last_age_hobby in book.items():
            f = open("file1.csv", "w+")
            fields = ["Card", "Name", "Surname", "Age", "Hobbie"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows({
                "Card": codekey,
                "Name": first_last_age_hobby[0],
                "Surname": first_last_age_hobby[1],
                "Age": first_last_age_hobby[2],
                "Hobbie": first_last_age_hobby[3]
            })
            print("Data saved to csv")
        return True
    except IOError:
        print("I/O ERROR")
        return False
```

You were missing a loop, to grab the four values for each of the keys. Happy Coding!

Comment: Hello Sam, thanks for your answer.
Line:
>>>for codekey, first_last_age_hobby = book.items():

Gives me a syntax error, so i tried replacing it with:

>>>for g in book.items(): 

And line:

>>>writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)

With:

>>>writer = g.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)

But gives me an error:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'DictWriter'

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `for codekey, first_last_age_hobby in book.items():` -- `in` instead of `=`, that was a typo. If you are in python3, book.items() gives you two values at a time, a `key` and `value` pair.  With your code change you are assigning BOTH the key and value to one variable, the tuple `g`. And then trying to use `g.DictWriter`, which doesn't exist. Try going back to my updated code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam!!!, worked fine after including your suggestions .

Comment: Great! If you liked my answer please upvote and select it as correct, it helps build the community of responders!